# python - pandas - split text column with no delimiter in to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's take the following example `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 2348], ['bar', 6132], ['baz',5843]], columns = list('ab'))

     a     b
0  foo  2348
1  bar  6132
2  baz  5843
```

I would like to have the following result where all the digits in column `b` are split apart.

```
     a  b  c  d  e
0  foo  2  3  4  8
1  bar  6  1  3  2
2  baz  5  8  4  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the type to `str` and then `apply` `list` to make a list of the chars, then construct a `Series` so it returns a df that you can add back as new columns:

```
In [13]:
df[['b','c','d','e']] = df['b'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).astype(int)
df

Out[13]:
     a  b  c  d  e
0  foo  2  3  4  8
1  bar  6  1  3  2
2  baz  5  8  4  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
#convert column b to string
df['b'] = df.b.astype(str)

#indexing with str
df['c'] = df.b.str[1]
df['d'] = df.b.str[2]
df['e'] = df.b.str[3]
df['b'] = df.b.str[0]

#if need convert columns to int
df[['b','c','d','e']] = df[['b','c','d','e']].astype(int)
print df
     a  b  c  d  e
0  foo  2  3  4  8
1  bar  6  1  3  2
2  baz  5  8  4  3
```